# Saving Data retrieved from Twitter utilizing Python to a text file?

Tags: python, caching, twitter

Hello all I am currently working on doing some research and was utilizing the twitter api to collect information. I wrote some code to query for specific tweets in python and would like to save the results to a text file, yet my code is only returning the last tweet of the tweets returned can anyone tell me how I may correct this and what's wrong?
The following is a sample of my code in Python only saving the last tweet instead of all of the returned tweets:

```
u = urllib2.urlopen('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?geocode=29.762778,-95.383056,10.0mi&page=1&rpp=10')
datares = json.load(u)
pprint.pprint(datares)
for tweet in datares['results']:
  print tweet['text']
  archive=tweet['text']
  unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', archive).encode('ascii','ignore')
  with codecs.open('HTXtweets.txt',mode='w', encoding='utf-8',errors='replace') as cache:
    cache.write(archive)
    cache.closed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening the file in each iteration of the loop through the results. This recreates it from scratch each time.

You should open it before the loop - you don't need to close it at the end, as that will happen automatically when the `with` statement finishes.

Comment: I guess this is a better way to go than my suggestion since you only open the file once.

Comment: Thanks Daniel your suggestion did the trick and thanks for the tip extra tip of not needing the close at the end really appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you open the file for writing in each iteration. This will replace existing content in the file. Try using the flag `'a'` (as in append) instead when opening the file.

Comment: Thanks McFjodor for the feedback I guess it took a fresh pair of eyes to see my sillymistake I appreciate it!